# Performing onActivityResult functionality in Service

Tags: android, service

I am using this speech to text. It is working fine in an Activity.

Oncreate:

```
    // initialize imageButton
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    // this method onclick called when speak button clicked
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // we create intent for speech recognization
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            // here we set language for recognize
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

            try {
                // this line start google voice activity with data we set in
                // previous lines and set request code =RERESULT_SPEECH=1
                // you don't need to understand this in depth because these
                // are built in function for get voice from app
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);


            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                // if device give exception it means it not support speech
                // to text
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();// show toast message
            }
        }
    });
```

OnActivityResult:

```
// this method called when user stop speaking and then we get text of speech
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    // request code 1 means speech activity
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        // if user speech any word and stop speak and data not null
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            // voice data stored in arraylist as a text so we get this text
            // and set in textfield
            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            // setText field with text which user speak
            Log.i("", text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
}
```

But I want to do this whole work in service. And in service, there is no onActivityResult(). How to perform this action in a Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there are no way to `startActivityForResult` in a `Service`.

But, you can create a `Activity` with transparent theme. This `Activity` will start `Google SPEECH Activity`, get the result data and transfer to the `Service`.

Comment: I already tried this but that doesn't worked, check [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8611812/)

Comment: @UnityBeginner In the service, we must have two constants: RESULT_SPEECH and ACTION_START. When user click button to start Service just start the Service with custom-flag in intent is ACTION_START. While service run and meet your condition you will NewActivity. This activity will start SPEECH Activity and return result data to NewActivity. The NewActivity will call startService again with intent's data is RESULT_SPEECH (for custom-falg) and the speech result data. Read this link for more http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: we haven't used ACTION_START in the code above and it is working perfectly n the same is the requirment in service